# ClassCastException even after providing casting class

Tags: java, jpa, classcastexception

I have the following code snippet, when I execute, I am getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to test.hr.Employee

**Code:**

```
  Query query = 
            getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Employee.findEmployees");
        List<Employee> result = query.getResultList();
        if (result != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                Employee emp = (Employee) result.get(i);
                log.info("Employee =" +emp.getNumber());
            }
```

**JPQL:**

```
select DISTINCT u.projectId,e.empNumber from Employee e LEFT JOIN  
e.userProjectsList u  JOIN u.projectMaster pm
where e.userNumber='SMITH'
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: and what is the JPQL query?

Comment: cause is that [Ljava.lang.Object; is the name for Object[], the representing the array of Object. where you are casting with Employee.

Comment: @NeilStockton I have included my JPQL in my question.

Comment: So change the JPQL query to "SELECT e from Employee e".

Comment: why you think your JPQL return Employee you have selected only `e.empNumber` instead select `e`

Comment: @NeilStockton What if I have a join condition in JPQL?

Comment: what if you do? what has that got to do with anything? we can't see your entities, and you said what your query was above ... which had no JOIN.

Comment: To paraphrase @singhakash: why do you think a query that returns a projectId and an empNumber will give you a resultSet row that you can somehow cast to an `Employee`? Return the correct result set and you can cast it to the correct class.

Comment: So you're basically changing the question by updating your JPQL. At the end of the day, if you have a result clause that is not the candidate type then you get Object[] returned. This is documented in any decent JPA docs so suggest that you read some

Comment: Yes @NeilStockton, I understood my obvious mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your query don't return an Employee but an Object array instead (an  array of objects containing the Project id and the Employee id), So here you have two choices:

**1-** Change your `JPQL` query like this:

```
SELECT e from Employee e
```

**2-** Or change your code to read from an object:

```
Query query = 
        getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Employee.findEmployees");
    List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
    if (result != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Object[] emp = (Object[]) result.get(i);
            log.info("Employee =" +emp[0]);
        }
```

**EDIT:**

And referring to your edit you need to do:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Object[] emp = (Object[]) result.get(i);
            log.info("Employee Number=" +emp[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped to resolve my issue. Appreciated.

Comment: What is the best approach to assign Object[] to values to Java POJO class   or something similar to that?

Comment: Well you can simply iterate over this Object array and create a new Employee in each iteration `Employee Empl = new Employee();` and set its Number using `Empl.setNumber(emp[0]);` if you already defined getter and setter for Number.

Answer (score 1):

problem is at

```
Employee emp = (Employee) result.get(i);
```

try this

```
Object[] emp = (Object[]) result.get(i);
```

now next you have to see what you have in `emp` object

Comment: This might work but it doesn't help figure out why the OP can't cast to Employee. Explain how `Object[] emp` can be used to get an instance of `Employee`.

Comment: both are different types how they can convert Object[] into Employee even they have no relationship in between like inheritance ?

Comment: Yes, what you say is right. But it doesn't help answer the question. Make some inferences, draw some conclusions, help the OP resolve the problem.

Comment: i got your point. but i have just pointed out that where is problem in their existing scenario.